# Contraint to set one column as the sum of two others automatically

Tags: oracle

I'm wondering is it possible to use a constraint to set the value of one column to be sum of two others. For example given the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Room (
Room_Num NUMBER(3),
Room_Band_ID NUMBER(2),
Room_Type_ID NUMBER(2),
Room_Price NUMBER(4),
PRIMARY KEY (Room_Num),
FOREIGN KEY(Room_Band_ID)
REFERENCES Room_Band(Room_Band_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Room_Type_ID)
REFERENCES Room_Type(Room_Type_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE Booking (
Booking_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
GuestID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
StaffID NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
Payment_ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
Room_Num NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
CheckInDate DATE NOT NULL,
CheckOutDate DATE NOT NULL,
Booking NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
Price NUMBER(4),
PRIMARY KEY (Booking_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(GuestID)
REFERENCES Guest(GuestID),
FOREIGN KEY(StaffID)
REFERENCES Staff(StaffID),
FOREIGN KEY(Payment_ID)
REFERENCES Payment(Payment_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Room_Num)
REFERENCES Room(Room_Num)
);
```

I know it is possible to do something like:

```
   Constraint PriceIs CHECK (Booking.Price=(Room.Room_Price*
   (Booking.CheckOutDate - Booking.CheckInDate)));
```

Is it also possible to set up a constraint that doesn't just ensure that the price is correct, but to calculate the price automatically into the price field for the relevant tuple?

Update,

So I've tried to set up a trigger as follows:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE trigger PriceCompute
   AFTER INSERT ON Booking
   FOR each row
   BEGIN
   UPDATE Booking
   SET 
   SELECT (Room.Room_Price*(Booking.CheckOutDate - Booking.CheckInDate))
   INTO
   Booking.Price
   FROM Booking
   JOIN ROOM ON Booking.Room_Num = Room.Room_Num
   END;
   /
```

But I'm getting the following errors back:
[image: Cmd prompt errors returned from trigger compilation]

Can anyone see where I'm going astray here, as its beyond me.

Comment: To compute, you will use a trigger rather than a constraint.

Comment: Or create a view to calculate the column values on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here are your options. Listed in order of my personal preference:

1. You can have a table without this column. And create a view that will be calculating this column on a fly.
2. You may use oracle virtual columns

   ```
   create table  Room (
   ...
   price     NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (room_price*(checkOut-checkIn)) VIRTUAL,
   ...)
   ```
3. You may use actual column (same as 2, per Dave Costa):

   ```
   create table  Room (
   ...
   price     AS (room_price*(checkOut-checkIn)),
   ...)
   ```
4. You can write trigger to populate it (like Mat M suggested)
5. You can write stored procedure, but it will be an overkill in this situation

Comment: I like this answer, but I think there is not any difference between your options #2 and #3 (in Oracle 11g at least).  The documentation states that both `GENERATED ALWAYS` and `VIRTUAL` are optional keywords when creating a virtual column.  So I believe these two commands produce exactly the same result.

Comment: Oh - also I just realized the question involves fields in two different tables.  So the virtual column is not possible in this case.

Comment: You can use an underlying PL/SQL function to do the calculation across tables and define a virtual column using this function.

Comment: Sorry, I also miss that it is 2 tables. In general, I would advice against business logic (like your formula) in triggers, because it is a hidden piece of code. I would go with package/procedure.

Comment: I went with the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255934/complicated-cube-query Thanks for putting me on track guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to put a trigger on both tables for whenever the price value of the room is changed or the checkout/in dates are changed, it will update the PriceIs field from your calculation.

If you don't need the calculated portion stored in an actual field, you can always create a view that calculates it whenever you look at the view.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution is to use a view that calculates the value on the fly.  But regarding your attempt to create a trigger, you should use `:new.<column_name>` to refer to the values being inserted into the `Booking` table.  You don't need to perform updates and queries on that table to get or modify the values in the row that is being inserted*.  You just refer to them as variables.  So you would want to do something like:

```
SELECT (Room.Room_Price*(:new.CheckOutDate - :new.CheckInDate))
   INTO
   :new.Price
   FROM ROOM WHERE :new.Room_Num = Room.Room_Num
```

*In fact, you can't perform queries or updates on the table whose modification invoked the trigger in the first place.  You would get the infamous "mutating table" error if your trigger actually compiled and ran.