# Complicated Cube Query

Tags: oracle

I'm working on a fairly complicated view, which calculates the total cost of a guest's stayed based on data pulled from four different tables. The output however is not exactly what I want. My code is

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Price AS
   SELECT UNIQUE
   Booking.Booking_ID AS "Booking", 
   Booking.GuestID AS "Guest ID",
   Room.Room_Price*(Booking.CheckOutDate-Booking.CheckInDate) AS "Room Price",
   Add_Ons.Price AS "Add ons Price",
   Room.Room_Price*(Booking.CheckOutDate-Booking.CheckInDate) + (Add_Ons.Price) AS "Total Price"
   FROM Booking  JOIN Room ON Room.Room_Num = Booking.Room_Num
                 JOIN Booking_Add_Ons ON Booking.Booking_ID = Booking_Add_Ons.Booking_ID
                 JOIN Add_ons ON Booking_Add_Ons.Add_On_ID = Add_Ons.Add_On_ID
   ORDER BY Booking.Booking_ID;
```

Now, I'm trying to get this to return the total cost of all Addons, plus the cost of the hotel rooms as the total price, however it is returning the cost of the rooms + each of the addons on separate lines. As follows:

[image: Command prompt return of the price view]

My question is, is it possible to use something like CUBE, or SUM to add up the rows, so that there is only one entry for each of the Bookings with the total price of all add-ons accounted for?

Comment: Try this 
select Booking, sum(total_price) from price group by rollup(booking);

Comment: Oh my god I am so close with this. I'll give it a bit of tweaking to get it working perfectly but thanks so much!